# filter parameter value gephi 0.9.2

Tags: gephi

I need suggestion about building network graph. I am novice in building this kind of graph. Previously, I have used gephi 0.9.1 which allow user to add parameter e.g degree range between 20 - 30 by using slide bar or checked box, but it version 0.9.2 there is no slide bar or check box. So how can I add the value for my filter parameter. Do I have to write some code to generate the graph.

Besides the above issue, It seems like gephi itself does not allow to import huge data like 25 millions of edges. Do I have to used additional plugin or software to manipulate the data or just separate the data and build the graph separately and then just combine them later. Are there any tutorial or books available. I have read the gephi mannual and tried some tutorial video on youtube before, but it seems insufficient for my solutions.

Thanks for you guys suggestions and help in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is it how the filters in version 0.9.2 look for me. As you see there is still a slider at the bottom of the **Filters** pane.

[image]